# How can I change the text color of Chrome's input date placeholder?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input

I have searched everywhere and cannot find how to change the text color of Chrome's shadow DOM input date element. Most placeholders have a soft gray color but Chrome's shadow DOM text is black and then when you add the date, the text color stays the same. Chrome already has shadow DOM text as "mm/dd/yyyy" and that's the text color that I need to change.

```
<input type="date"/>
```

Comment: It's not a placeholder (which is defined by `placeholder="Some Placeholder"`)

Comment: So what is it then? @Adam

Comment: Part of the shadow DOM of the date element. All other `placeholder`s are defined in HTML by the `placeholder` attribute, this is not, therefore, it's not a placeholder. Styling the shadow DOM: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/

Comment: did you mean value that came after date selection in box

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507119/is-it-possible-to-style-the-default-placeholder-text-on-an-html5-input-type-dat/14508957#14508957

Answer (score 31):

If the input field is required you can use the [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ainvalid) selector like this:

```css
input[type=date]:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" required /><br>
```

Another solution is to add a class to the input which you remove when a value has been entered.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('date');
el.onchange = function() {
    if (el.value === '') {
        el.classList.add("empty");
    } else {
        el.classList.remove("empty");
    }
}
```

```css
.empty {
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" class="empty" />
```

> **NOTE:** My second example (the one with a class) will be applied in all browsers.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507119/is-it-possible-to-style-the-default-placeholder-text-on-an-html5-input-type-dat) has been answered before, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't solve my problem original problem though. I was looking for something that would have the generic 'placeholder' have a text color of gray, but if you input your own value, that value text color would then be black. Pretty much how most input elements work.

Comment: It's almost how this works. Except you need to enter a valid date in order for the color to change. Not sure if it's possible to change the color of a date input when some value has been entered.

Answer (score 5):

Adding my super simple React solution here, for anyone who needs it!

```css
/* placeholder text style */
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-text,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
  color: #888;
}

/* regular text style */
input[type="date"].date-input--has-value::-webkit-datetime-edit-text,
input[type="date"].date-input--has-value::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
input[type="date"].date-input--has-value::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
input[type="date"].date-input--has-value::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
  color: #f8f9fa;
}
```

```html
<input
  type="date"
  name="date"
  className={(this.state.date) ? 'date-input--has-value' : ''}
  value={this.state.date}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Basically just trigger a CSS class based on whether the state value exists or not. Only works for controlled components, obviously - but if you already have this set up, then adding a quick conditional operator and some CSS styling is really easy!

The colors I used are what I needed for my dark-theme website, but you can obviously change them to whatever you like. The four different CSS selectors are needed to fully target the entire text field - the first one targets just the '/' (or '.', depending on locale) date separators, and the next three individually target the month, day, and year parts of the field, respectively. Yes, you *could* make each individual one a different color, if you felt the need...

--

Ignore the 'Run code snippet' bit, as it obviously won't work without a full React component connected up and so on. I just used the snippet view, as it's a nice way to show both CSS and HTML side by side.

Comment: Time color did not change

Comment: @ThilankaDeSilva - you'll need to also update these:
`-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field`
`-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field`
`-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field`

Answer (score -7):

Better easy way by CSS is just to it like this:

```
input[type=time]{
color: blue;
opacity: 34%;
```

}

Comment: Please read the topic before posting.
1. The subject is changing the color of the placeholder, and/but not that of the value selected.
2. The subject is the native date, not the native time input.

Answer (score -9):

You can do it like this:

```
input[type=date] {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer ended up in the low quality posts review queue. When formatting multi-line code samples please format them as a code block. Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation.